# Let $f:[0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be continuous and non-increasing...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $u_n=f(n)$ for $n\geq 0$, $v_n=\int_{1}^nf(x)dx$ for $n\geq 1$. Show that the limit 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ \left( \sum_{k=1}^n u_k\right) - v_n\right]$$ exists.

Rewriting the term in the limit this is

$$\sum_{k=1}^nf(k) - \int_1^n f(x)dx \leq nf(1) - \int_1^n f(x)dx$$ since $f$ is non-increasing. From here I am completely stuck and not sure if I am going in the correct direction. I'm certain I have to use properties of $f$ and its integral, but I cannot think of what to use. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $M=\sup_{[1,n]}\{f(x)\}=f(1)$ and $m=\inf_{[1,n]}\{f(x)\} = f(n)$, then $nf(1) - \int_1^n f(x)dx\leq nf(1)-f(n)(n-1)$. Does this help me?

Comment: Uh, maybe my inequality in my comment should be $stuff\leq nf(1)-f(1)(n-1)=f(1)$. So $\sum_{k=1}^nf(k) - \int_1^n f(x)dx\leq f(1)$ for all $n$, so the limit exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's enough write
\begin{equation}
\int_1^n f(x)=\sum_{k=2}^n\int_{k-1}^kf(x)
\end{equation}
Now, using also that f is nonincreasing, the limit become
\begin{equation}
\left[ \left( \sum_{k=1}^n u_k\right) - v_n\right]=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(f(k-1)-\int_{k-1}^kf(x)\right)+f(n)\le \sum_{k=2}^n (f(k-1)-f(k))+f(n)=f(1)
\end{equation}
Hence the sequence $\{ \sum_{k=2}^n\left(f(k-1)-\int_{k-1}^kf(x)\right)+f(n)\}_{n\in Z_+}$ is bounded and, clearly increasing.
Then the limit exist.